# AngularJS nested ng-repeat in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJs and have come across an issue with Json data with nested arrays.

I have simplified the code to a simple html doc, this can be found below.

The first property {{HelloMessage}} is working and gets populated with the string value stored in the property HelloMessage, but the ng-repeat is not.

After looking online, I discovered that I in fact had an array within an array, so assumed that I needed to have an ng-repeat within an ng-repeat, but it is not working. I am quite sure that it is something simple that I have done wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 ng-controller="myController">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>UserId</th>
                <th>DisplayName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="stream in Data.Records">
                <tr ng-repeat="record in stream.Users">
                    <td>{{stream.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{stream.User}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{stream.Description}}
                    </td>
                    <!--<td>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="b in value">
                                    <td>{{b.user}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>-->
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', []).controller('myController',
                        function ($scope) {


                            $scope.helloMessage = "Hi";


                            $scope.Data = [{
                                Success: true,
                                ErrorMessage: null,
                                SuccessMessage: null,
                                Records: [{
                                    "CreatedBy": "Mickey Mouse",
                                    "CreatedDate": "2015-08-17T13:16:22.713",
                                    "CreatedDateDisplay": "17-08-2015",
                                    "Description": "Test 1",
                                    "Id": 7546798576985769857,
                                    "Name": "Test 1",
                                    "UpdatedBy": "",
                                    "UpdatedDate": null,
                                    "UpdatedDateDisplay": null,
                                    "User": null,
                                    "UserId": 0,
                                    "Users": [{
                                        "Users": [{
                                            "Id": 7546798576985769858,
                                            "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
                                            "DisplayName": "Daffy Duck"
                                        }, {
                                            "Id": 7546798576985769859,
                                            "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
                                            "DisplayName": "Pluto"
                                        }
                                        ],
                                        "User": "Bugs Bunny",
                                        "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
                                        "Name": "Test 2",
                                        "Description": "Test 2",
                                        "Id": 7546798576985769857,
                                        "CreatedBy": "Goofy",
                                        "CreatedDate": "2015-08-25T14:03:28.083",
                                        "UpdatedBy": "Porky Pig",
                                        "UpdatedDate": "2017-03-27T08:19:36.077",
                                        "CreatedDateDisplay": "25-08-2015",
                                        "UpdatedDateDisplay": "27-03-2017"
                                    }
                                    ]
                                }
                                ]
                            }
                            ];



                        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No errors are throw in Chrome Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the ng-repeat as

```
<tr ng-repeat="stream in Data[0].Records[0].Users[0].Users">
</tr>
```

Use

```
    <td>{{stream.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{stream.UserId}}</td>
    <td>{{stream.DisplayName}}</td>
```

instead of

```
<td>{{stream.Id}}</td>
<td>{{stream.User}}</td>
<td>{{stream.Description}}</td>
```

```js
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.helloMessage = "Hi";
  $scope.Data = [{
    Success: true,
    ErrorMessage: null,
    SuccessMessage: null,
    Records: [{
      "CreatedBy": "Mickey Mouse",
      "CreatedDate": "2015-08-17T13:16:22.713",
      "CreatedDateDisplay": "17-08-2015",
      "Description": "Test 1",
      "Id": 7546798576985769857,
      "Name": "Test 1",
      "UpdatedBy": "",
      "UpdatedDate": null,
      "UpdatedDateDisplay": null,
      "User": null,
      "UserId": 0,
      "Users": [{
        "Users": [{
          "Id": 7546798576985769858,
          "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
          "DisplayName": "Daffy Duck"
        }, {
          "Id": 7546798576985769859,
          "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
          "DisplayName": "Pluto"
        }],
        "User": "Bugs Bunny",
        "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
        "Name": "Test 2",
        "Description": "Test 2",
        "Id": 7546798576985769857,
        "CreatedBy": "Goofy",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-08-25T14:03:28.083",
        "UpdatedBy": "Porky Pig",
        "UpdatedDate": "2017-03-27T08:19:36.077",
        "CreatedDateDisplay": "25-08-2015",
        "UpdatedDateDisplay": "27-03-2017"
      }]
    }]
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>{{helloMessage}}</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>UserId</th>
          <th>DisplayName</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="stream in Data[0].Records[0].Users[0].Users">
          <td>{{stream.Id}}</td>
          <td>{{stream.UserId}}</td>
          <td>
            {{stream.DisplayName}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define your controller to body level as following.

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
```

You have defined it as h1 level so it is not accessible.

I have made changes in your code please as following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title

</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>{{helloMessage}}</h1>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>UserId</th>
                    <th>DisplayName</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="stream in Data[0].Records[0].Users[0].Users">
                    <td>{{stream.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{stream.UserId}}</td>
                    <td>{{stream.DisplayName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>    

    <script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('app', []).controller('myController',
                            function ($scope) {
                                $scope.helloMessage = "Hi";
                                $scope.Data = [{
                                    Success: true,
                                    ErrorMessage: null,
                                    SuccessMessage: null,
                                    Records: [{
                                        "CreatedBy": "Mickey Mouse",
                                        "CreatedDate": "2015-08-17T13:16:22.713",
                                        "CreatedDateDisplay": "17-08-2015",
                                        "Description": "Test 1",
                                        "Id": 7546798576985769857,
                                        "Name": "Test 1",
                                        "UpdatedBy": "",
                                        "UpdatedDate": null,
                                        "UpdatedDateDisplay": null,
                                        "User": null,
                                        "UserId": 0,
                                        "Users": [{
                                            "Users": [{
                                                "Id": 7546798576985769858,
                                                "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
                                                "DisplayName": "Daffy Duck"
                                            }, {
                                                "Id": 7546798576985769859,
                                                "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
                                                "DisplayName": "Pluto"
                                            }],
                                            "User": "Bugs Bunny",
                                            "UserId": 7546798576985769857,
                                            "Name": "Test 2",
                                            "Description": "Test 2",
                                            "Id": 7546798576985769857,
                                            "CreatedBy": "Goofy",
                                            "CreatedDate": "2015-08-25T14:03:28.083",
                                            "UpdatedBy": "Porky Pig",
                                            "UpdatedDate": "2017-03-27T08:19:36.077",
                                            "CreatedDateDisplay": "25-08-2015",
                                            "UpdatedDateDisplay": "27-03-2017"
                                        }]
                                    }]
                                }];
                            });
    </script>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your JSON is full of arrays. It could probably be improved, but there is how you can display it in its current state. You don't need to nest `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in Data[0].Records[0].Users[0].Users">
        <td>{{user.Id}}</td>
        ...
</tbody>
```

## [Working JSFiddle of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/4k4fejqb/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, thank you all for your help. I have used Geethu Jose answer, but it still did not give me exactly what I was looking for, but after much head scratching I did come up with a solution for my problem. Instead of using the array placeholders [0] I needed access the arrays themselves at the different levels, so I had to change the code to the following.

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <h1>{{helloMessage}}</h1>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in Data">
                    <td>
                        <table ng-repeat="records in data">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>UserId</th>
                                    <th>User</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{records.UserId}}</td>
                                    <td>{{records.User}}</td>
                                    <td>{{records.Name}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Id</th>
                                                    <th>UserId</th>
                                                    <th>DisplayName</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="streamUser in records.Users">
                                                <td>{{streamUser.Id}}</td>
                                                <td>{{streamUser.UserId}}</td>
                                                <td>{{streamUser.DisplayName}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```